# Running SSOM on non sharepoint

Tags: 2013

Is it possible to run SSOM on non SharePoint ? we can't use CSOM as for some cases we need to elevate privileges ?

We can deploy a web services to same server but it needs to be in IIS not SharePoint as we don't want clients to have down time if we keep updating it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run SSOM on non sharepoint box.

You can create a web service and deploy it on one of your front end server. If you don't deploy it as a SharePoint webservice the only problem you will face is with authentication. The web service will be run under the the application pool identity. But sure you can easily do the elevated privileges with ease.

Comment: Hi, How can I get SPContext on a web service which is hosted on IIS but in same server as SharePoint, I thought it was not possible

Comment: SPContext will be null.. you should use new SPSite and New SPWeb

Comment: Thank you for confirming but I didn't get using  new SPSite or SPWeb bit :)

Comment: I mean create new object instead of using the context object.. SPSite sp = new SPSiite(siteUrl);